# Turn specific animations off on Gnome

Tags: gnome, animations, minimize, maximized

Simple, I want to disable minimise & maximise animations as i hate them but want to keep workspace and other animations as they work for me and i like them. I know we can do it in KDE but Can i do that with Gnome?

Comment: You haven't said what release, but look in `gnome-tweaks`  (it'll turn all on or off though... some extensions can select, but will be version specific I believe)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.  Gnome 3.36.3

Comment: In Gnome, you cannot tune individual animations without editing source code, I am afraid.

Comment: thats a bummer :(